# Reactive sliders and ggplots not updating - due to input contained in a list?

Tags: r, shiny

I have three drop down menus that filter two separate data frames. In addition, there is checkbox that shows up in the sidebar panel during specific filtration that is used to generate dynamic plots.

The problem is that there are: 1. Multiple sliders showing up, but they are not dynamic; 2. I can't seem to adjust the multiple plots based on the sliders b/c the sliders are not dynamic. I've removed a bunch of code that is working as it makes the server side code even longer and does not pertain to this issue.

Based on troubleshooting, I think the issue is the following: 1. The variable input$meterslider is a list and is not being loaded properly in observe({}) or int the object plots(). Apologies, if this is actually an easy fix - I've been hunting for an answer without much luck. Any help much appreciated! Apologies for the long code, but I wanted to be as comprehensive as possible.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(  
sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("selectsector"),
    uiOutput("selectfacility"),
    uiOutput("selectcurvename"),
    uiOutput("selectms"),
    actionButton("do", "Click me to get new plots"),   

mainPanel(
 tabsetPanel(
   tabPanel(
     fluidRow(
       column(12, 
              uiOutput("meterslider"),
              plotOutput("metersites", height = 750, width = 1000), style = 'padding:50px'))
         )
        )  
       )
      )
  ))

x <- c("shiny", "data.table", "dplyr", "lubridate", "stringr", "extrafont",
   "ggplot2", "httr", "tidyr", "gridExtra", "scales")
lapply(x, require, character.only = T)

MC <- MC %>%
      mutate(Building_Category = ifelse(Building_Category == 
             "manufacturing", "Manufacturing", Building_Category),
             Sector = ifelse(Curve_Name_Match == "CommercialIndustrial", 
             "Multiple", Sector),
             DOW = as.character(as.factor(wday(DateHour, label = T, abbr = 
             T))))

OHcurves <- OHcurves %>%
            mutate(Building_Category = ifelse(Building_Category == "All 
                   Residential", "Residential", Building_Category),
                   Curve_Name_Match = ifelse(grepl("^Intlight_Manu", 
                   Curve_Name_Match), "IntlightManufacturingCEUSBlend",
                               Curve_Name_Match),
                   DOW = as.character(as.factor(wday(Hour, label = T, abbr = 
                   T))))

function(input, output, session) { 
  sec <- unique(OHcurves$Sector)
  fac <- unique(OHcurves$Building_Category)
  cn <- unique(OHcurves$Curve_Name_Match) 
  meter <- unique(MC$Customer)

  output$selectsector <- renderUI({
  selectInput("sector", "Select Sector", as.list(sec), selected = sec[1])
  })

  output$selectfacility <- renderUI({
     if(is.null(input$sector)) {
         return()
     } else if(input$sector == "RS") {
         res <- selectizeInput("facility", "Select Facility", 
         as.list("Residential"), selected = "Residential")
         return(res)
     } else if(input$sector == "Multiple") {
         mult <- selectizeInput("facility", "Select Facility", 
         as.list("Other"), selected = "Other")
         return(mult)
     }
         fac <- fac[fac != "Residential"]
         selectizeInput("facility", "Select Facility", as.list(fac), 
         selected = fac[1])
     })

  output$selectcurvename <- renderUI({
     if(is.null(input$sector)) {
         return()
     } else if(is.null(input$facility)) {
         return()
     } else if(input$sector == "RS") {
         rescn <- OHcurves %>% filter(Sector == "RS")
         rescn <- sort(unique(rescn$Curve_Name_Match))
         res <- selectizeInput("curvename", "Select Curve Name", 
                as.list(rescn), selected = rescn[1])
         return(res)
     } else if(input$sector == "Multiple") {
         mult <- selectizeInput("curvename", "Select Curve Name", 
                 as.list("CommercialIndustrial"), selected = 
                 "CommercialIndustrial")
         return(mult)
     } else if (input$sector == "CI") {

         cicn <- OHcurves[which((OHcurves$Sector == input$sector) &
                           (OHcurves$Building_Category == input$facility)), 
                         ]
         cicn <- unique(cicn$Curve_Name_Match)
         selectizeInput("curvename", "Select Curve Name", as.list(cicn), selected = cicn[1])

      }
    })

  output$selectms <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(input$sector)) {
         return()
      } else if(is.null(input$facility)) {
         return()
      } else if(is.null(input$curvename)) {
         return()
      } else if(input$sector == "RS") {
         cust <- OHcurves[which((OHcurves$Sector %in% input$sector) & (OHcurves$Building_Category %in% input$facility) & (OHcurves$Curve_Name_Match %in% input$curvename)), ]
         cust <- unique(cust$Curve_Name_Match)
         rs <- MC %>% filter(Sector == "RS" & Building_Category == "Residential")
         cust <- rs[cust %in% rs$Curve_Name_Match]
         cust <- unique(cust$Customer)
         checkboxGroupInput("selectms", "Metered Sites: ", c(cust), c(cust))
      } else if(input$sector == "Multiple") {
         cust <- OHcurves[which((OHcurves$Sector %in% input$sector) & (OHcurves$Building_Category %in% input$facility) & (OHcurves$Curve_Name_Match %in% input$curvename)), ]
         cust <- unique(cust$Curve_Name_Match)
         mult <- MC %>% filter(Sector == "Multiple" & Building_Category == "Other")
         cust <- mult[cust %in% mult$Curve_Name_Match]
         cust <- unique(cust$Customer)
         checkboxGroupInput("selectms", "Metered Sites: ", c(cust), c(cust))
      } else if(input$sector == "CI") {
         ci <- MC[((MC$Sector %in% input$sector) & (MC$Building_Category %in% input$facility) & (MC$Curve_Name_Match %in% input$curvename)),]
         ci <- unique(ci$Customer)
         checkboxGroupInput("selectms", "Metered Sites: ", c(ci), c(ci))
      }
    })

  output$meterslider <- renderUI({
      if(is.null(input$do) || input$do == 0) {
         return(NULL)
      } 
      if(length(input$selectms) == 0 || is.null(input$selectms) || 
         input$selectms == 0){
         return(NULL)
      }
      else{
         subset <- MC[which((MC$Sector %in% input$sector) &
                         (MC$Building_Category %in% input$facility) &
                         (MC$Curve_Name_Match %in% input$curvename) &
                         (MC$Customer %in% input$selectms)), ]

         sub <- split(subset, input$selectms)
         dates <- lapply(1:length(sub), function(x) 
         x <- sub[[x]] %>%
              dplyr::select(DateHour))
         names(dates) <- unique(subset$Customer)

         ms.min <- lapply(1:length(dates), function(x)
       as.POSIXct(min(dates[[x]]$DateHour), origin ='1970-01-01', tz = "EST")
       )
         ms.max <-lapply(1:length(dates), function(x)
       as.POSIXct(max(dates[[x]]$DateHour), origin ='1970-01-01', tz = "EST")
       )
         lapply(1:length(dates), function(x) 
               sliderInput("slider", paste(names(dates)[[x]], "Adjust Dates Here:", sep = " "),
                    min = as.POSIXct(ms.min[[x]], origin ='1970-01-01', tz = "EST"),
                    max = as.POSIXct(ms.max[[x]], origin ='1970-01-01', tz = "EST"),
                    value = c(as.POSIXct(ms.min[[x]], origin ='1970-01-01', tz = "EST"), 
                              as.POSIXct(ms.max[[x]], origin ='1970-01-01', tz = "EST"))))
      }
    })

  observe({
    slide <- input$meterslider
    lapply(1:length(slide), function(x)
           updateSliderInput(session, "meterslider", value = c(slide[[x]], slide[[x]])))
    })


  plots <- reactive({ 
      input$do
      isolate({                                                                                                                  
      if(is.null(input$sector)) {
         return(NULL)
      }
      if(is.null(input$facility)) {
         return(NULL)
      }
      if(is.null(input$curvename)) {
         return(NULL)
      }
      if(is.null(input$selectms)) {
         return(NULL)
      }
      if(length(input$selectms) > 0) { 
         subset <- MC[which((MC$Sector %in% input$sector) &
                         (MC$Building_Category %in% input$facility) &
                         (MC$Curve_Name_Match %in% input$curvename) &
                         (MC$Customer %in% input$selectms)), ]

         sub <- split(subset, input$selectms)

         if (is.null(input$meterslider) || input$meterslider == 0) {
             sub <- lapply(1:length(sub), function(x) 
             p <- ggplot(sub[[x]], aes(x = DateHour, y = HourlyCurve)) + geom_line() +  ylab("Energy Savings") +
            xlab("Time") + ggtitle(sub[[x]]$Customer) +
            theme(legend.position = "bottom", text=element_text(size=14, family="Gill Sans MT"),
                  panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
                  panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
                  axis.ticks = (element_line(color = "black", size = 1)),
                  axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
                  axis.text = element_text(color = "black")))
             return(sub)
         }

         if (!(is.null(input$meterslider))|| input$meterslider != 0) {
             slide <- input$meterslider
             slide <- lapply(1:length(slide), function(x)
             x <- seq(min(slide[[x]]), max(slide[[x]]), by = "hour"))

             sub <- lapply(1:length(sub), function(x) 
                       sub[[x]] %>% filter(DateHour %in% slide[[x]]))

             sub <- lapply(1:length(sub), function(x) 
                           p <- ggplot(sub[[x]], aes(x = DateHour, y = HourlyCurve)) + geom_line() +  ylab("Energy Savings") +
            xlab("Time") + ggtitle(sub[[x]]$Customer) + 
            theme(legend.position = "bottom", text=element_text(size=14, family="Gill Sans MT"),
                  panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
                  panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
                  axis.line.x = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
                  axis.ticks = (element_line(color = "black", size = 1)),
                  axis.line.y = element_line(color = "black", size = 1),
                  axis.text = element_text(color = "black")))
             return(sub)
         }
     }
     else {
         return(NULL)
     }

   })
 })

 output$metersites <- renderPlot({
     if(length(plots()) > 0) {
         print(do.call("grid.arrange", c(plots(), ncol = 2)))
     } else {
         return(NULL)
     }

 })
}
```

Comment: There is no slider with the id `meterslider` in your code but you read `input$meterslider` at some point. Start by investigating your ID management and please shorten the example if possible.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible by the way since `OHcurves` is missing

Comment: The uiOuput for meterslider is located in the mainPanel rather than the sidebarPanel. OHcurves is just above the server code. I will shorten the code and re-upload.

Comment: Yes I saw that. `meterslider` is an `output`, not an `input`. So you can't expect `input$meterslider` to do anything. As for `OHcurves`: The line you are referring to reads `OHcurves <- OHcurves %>%`, so `OHcurves` already has to be defined in order to make that line work...